# CommandBar: Style 'XamlDefaultCommandBar' not found

Tags: uno-platform

I did not find the resource key 'XamlDefaultCommandBar' as per [docs here](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/controls/CommandBar.html) in Application.Current.Resources.

However, I found the resource 'DefaultCommandBar'. Would that be the right one for the 'Windows' mode on non-UWP platforms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more detail on what you tried? The [`XamlDefaultCommandBar` resource](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/749539388e66adda6d0f3756a9c9ad8e2a3fd01a/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Controls/CommandBar/CommandBar.xaml#L205) is definitely present in Uno, and has been there since at least Uno 2.0. You should be able to access it from code-behind using:

```cs
#if !NETFXCORE
    var style = Application.Current.Resources["XamlDefaultCommandBar"] as Style;
#endif
```

or in Xaml using:

```xml
<CommandBar not_win:Style={StaticResource XamlDefaultCommandBar} />
```

(using the [`not_win` prefix](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-xaml.html#xaml-conditional-prefixes) because it's not provided by default by UWP).

In any case, Uno will use this style by default for `CommandBar`. You should only need to manually set it if you've [overridden the global settings](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/using-uno-ui.html#using-styles) to have Uno use native styles in other cases.

Comment: Hmm ... this did not work in UWP `Application.Current.Resources["XamlDefaultCommandBar"]`

... nor did I find the resource key `"XamlDefaultCommandBar"` when iterating through Application.Current.Resourecs.Keys

Comment: Indeed it's provided only by Uno, not by UWP. I've edited the response to make this clearer. However you should not need it on UWP.

Comment: Thanks, that helps @DavidOliver